# Jenkins Error after upgrade - "Not all environment variables could be successfully injected."

Tags: jenkins

After the upgrade from Jenkins "1.651.3" to "2.346.3 LTS".

My job log contains this message many times:
`ERROR: Not all environment variables could be successfully injected. Check for similarly-named environment variables.`

There is no clue. How to find which variables could not be successfully injected?

Comment: Going from "1.651.3" to "2.346.3 LTS" is a massive jump. I'm sure it would be of great interest to others if you [published a blog post](http://vondrnotes.blogspot.com/) on your experience, what steps you took, what issues you encountered, etc. Did you take it in one giant leap or stepped via each LTS? The guidance seems to be upgrade plugins if possible, step LTS, upgrade plugins if possible, repeat.,  Did you encounter any issues post 2.264.3 (tables to divs upgrade)? What plugins did you have installed?

Comment: Yea - I have notes. When there will be bigger progress I will evaluate if I will find it interesting.

Comment: The other interesting area would be if yo encountered any issues with the tighter security and permissions problems. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that message goes from [Environment Injector plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/)

It goes from class [EnvInjectEnvVarsContributor](https://github.com/jenkinsci/envinject-plugin/blob/044d76bf43abdcd8a548ee59d5f40353ebe85631/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/envinject/EnvInjectEnvVarsContributor.java)

And it seems that it is not an error. It is just a warning, that some property, already exists in environment variables.
[Responsilbe commit from history](https://github.com/jenkinsci/envinject-plugin/commit/25669f16a5b0bb20dc97cc29e8c237bec77ab2db)

```java
Map<String, String> result = jobPropertyInfo.getPropertiesContentMap(env);
if (result != null) {
    int expectedEnvSize = env.size() + result.size();
    env.putAll(result);
    if (env.size() != expectedEnvSize) {
        listener.error("Not all environment variables could be successfully injected. " +
                "Check for similarly-named environment variables.");
    }
}
```

To find which properties are confilicting I used this groovy script executed in the job like "Execute system Groovy script"

```
import hudson.model.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectJobProperty 
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

println "FIND CONFLICTING PROPERTIES GROOVY SCRIPT---------------------------- START" 
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('my_job')
println job
EnvInjectJobProperty jobProperty = (EnvInjectJobProperty) job.getProperty(EnvInjectJobProperty.class);
def jobPropertyInfo = jobProperty.getInfo();
def env = Jenkins.instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()[0].getEnvVars() 
Map<String, String> result = jobPropertyInfo.getPropertiesContentMap(env);
println "RESULT"
println result
println result.size()

println "ENV"
println env
println env.size()

println "FIND CONFLICTING PROPERTIES GROOVY SCRIPT---------------------------- END"
```

Maybe it will help to someone.